# SSIS execute sql commands stored in a column of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreach, ssis, etl

> Error: error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_WSTR). Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Using SSIS I have placed in a sql column commands that will convert a pdf to a blob they have been tested and work individually.  So I would like to query the table column pass it to a exec sql task and execute each command.  I have tried many different things currently I have a execute sql task resultset being set to "full result set"  in the ResultSet the name is set to 0 and variable is User::sqlcmds this goes into a foreach loop container with collection tab setting of ADO object source variable = User::sqlcmds  and Enumeration mode as Rows in the first table.  Variable Mappings tab has Variable = User::sqlcmdenu and Index set to 0.  Within the foreach container I have a execute sql task and the sqlstatement set to:

```sql
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql= CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000),'  ' + ?)
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Parameter mapping: Variable name=user::sqlcmds, Direction: Input, Datatype:NVARCHAR, parameter name inputsqlcmd.

what am I doing wrong?

Tried using data flow, now trying execute sql and foreach. neither works.

> Error: error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_WSTR). Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you just do all of this inside a stored procedure? SSIS can introduce unnecessary complications.

Comment: Does it work if you change your variable data type to object?

Comment: The exec sql task that generates input has a result set variable (sqlcmds) of type Object.  The For each Container has a user variable sqlcmdenu of type string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by going back to dataflow task:
oledb source has-> select convert(varchar(4000),cmd) cmd from attcmd

then used derived column to convert -> (DT_WSTR,4000)cmd   (this solves the non Unicode to Unicode problems).

this is input into oledb command with component properties tab set to -> 
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql= CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000),?) 
exec sp_executesql @sql WITH RESULT SETS NONE

be sure to set column mapping of the input column to Param_0!

Data type of input column is DT_WSTR and Param_0 data type is Unicode string [DT_WSTR].